# How to get the value of a property in javascript which has a dot in it's name?

Tags: javascript

I have a property with name 'pp.phaseName' in an object 'Config'

Whenever I try to access it like Config.pp.phaseName, it's throwing error.

I've tried using Config.(pp.phaseName), Config."pp.phaseName" etc. but none was working.

Please help me on how to do this.

Comment: Better name property like this `ppPhaseName` for future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the square bracket notation.

```
Config["pp.phaseName"]
```

Comment: Optional: Slap whoever it was that put . in a property name as a string.